# PyFFTW slower than SciPy FFT?

Tags: python, scipy, pyfftw

I tried solution presented here on Stackoverflow by User: henry-gomersall to repeat speed up FFT based convolution, but obtained different result.

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw
import scipy.signal
import timeit

class CustomFFTConvolution(object):

    def __init__(self, A, B, threads=1):

        shape = (np.array(A.shape) + np.array(B.shape))-1

        if np.iscomplexobj(A) and np.iscomplexobj(B):
            self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.fftn(
                    A, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.fftn(
                    B, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.ifftn(
                    self.fft_A_obj.get_output_array(), s=shape,
                    threads=threads)

        else:
            self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfftn(
                    A, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfftn(
                    B, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.irfftn(
                    self.fft_A_obj.get_output_array(), s=shape,
                    threads=threads)

    def __call__(self, A, B):

        fft_padded_A = self.fft_A_obj(A)
        fft_padded_B = self.fft_B_obj(B)

        return self.ifft_obj(fft_padded_A * fft_padded_B)

N = 200

A = np.random.rand(N, N, N)
B = np.random.rand(N, N, N)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()

C = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(A,B,"same")
print timeit.default_timer() - start_time

custom_fft_conv_nthreads = CustomFFTConvolution(A, B, threads=1)
C = custom_fft_conv_nthreads(A, B)
print timeit.default_timer() - start_time
```

PyFFTW is approx. 7x slower than SciPy FFT which differs from other users experiences. What is wrong in  this code? Python 2.7.9, PyFFTW 0.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing what you think you're doing, and what you think you're doing you shouldn't be doing either.

You're not doing what you think you're doing because your code above only defines `start_time` once (so your test for pyfftw includes not only the time consuming creation of the `CustomFFTConvolution` object, but also the scipy convolution!).

You shouldn't be doing what you think you're doing because you should use `timeit` to test this sort of thing.

So, with some file `foo.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw
import scipy.signal

class CustomFFTConvolution(object):

    def __init__(self, A, B, threads=1):

        shape = (np.array(A.shape) + np.array(B.shape))-1

        if np.iscomplexobj(A) and np.iscomplexobj(B):
            self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.fftn(
                    A, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.fftn(
                    B, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.ifftn(
                    self.fft_A_obj.get_output_array(), s=shape,
                    threads=threads)

        else:
            self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfftn(
                    A, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfftn(
                    B, s=shape, threads=threads)
            self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.irfftn(
                    self.fft_A_obj.get_output_array(), s=shape,
                    threads=threads)

    def __call__(self, A, B):

        fft_padded_A = self.fft_A_obj(A)
        fft_padded_B = self.fft_B_obj(B)

        return self.ifft_obj(fft_padded_A * fft_padded_B)

N = 200

A = np.random.rand(N, N, N)
B = np.random.rand(N, N, N)
```

In ipython, you can get the following:

```
In [1]: %run foo.py

In [2]: timeit scipy.signal.fftconvolve(A,B,"same")
1 loops, best of 3: 8.38 s per loop

In [3]: custom_fft_conv_nthreads = CustomFFTConvolution(A, B, threads=1)

In [4]: timeit custom_fft_conv_nthreads(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.9 s per loop
```

and with multiple threads:

```
In [5]: custom_fft_conv_nthreads = CustomFFTConvolution(A, B, threads=4)

In [6]: timeit custom_fft_conv_nthreads(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.81 s per loop
```

If you correct your code to do what you think it's doing by inserting `start_time = timeit.default_timer()` before `C = custom_fft_conv_nthreads(A, B)`, you get something closer to what is expected:

```
10.8795630932
8.31241607666
```

Comment: I know what I am doing. I  substracted time used by scipy.signal.fftconvolve from  time returned by timeit.default_timer() and then I estimated "PyFFTW is approx. 7x slower"

Comment: To reproduce Your comments I added start_time before custom_fft_conv_nthreads. I testes my code in loop: first run: 6.0643529892 (Scipy fft convolve)
35.0755908489 (PyFFTW), second and each another 6.10961890221 (Scipy fft convolve) 5.85012698174 (PyFFTW) (so slightly faster). Unfortunately in my program, I make series of convolutions  each with bigger kernel, so I can't get speedup with PyFFTW.

Comment: Your code as you've written it is including the time from `fftconvolve` in the computing of the pyfftw result. You need to reinitialise it. Secondly, you shouldn't be doing that anyway - that's what timeit is for. FFTW is designed to work by trying various options and then working out the fastest - this is what takes the time in the object creation phase. It is possible to use flags that take less time, for which I suggest you going to read the docs. It's almost certainly true that you can use a single size (or a small number of sizes) for your convolution, so you don't need to plan every loop

Comment: Thank for Your suggestions @HenryGomersall. What I actually do is: `for _ in range(N): fftconvolve((1000,1000,100), kernel_n)`, where kernel is (11,11,11); (13,13,13); and so on. Kernel grows up every loop's run. To obtain linear convolution, plan must change its size every loop. So, to sum up I have no idea how to use (if possible) plan from previous convolution.

Comment: Oh, in that case it's easy. When you're doing an FFT convolution, you necessarily have a pair of intermediate arrays of the same (full) size. `pyfftw` handles this by using a wrapper class that inserts data into the correct part of the array (the `shape` parameter dictates this). You can do this manually - just create an FFTW object for the size of the output array, and then populate it as necessary from your growing kernel. If the kernel is always growing, you don't even need to zero out the previous kernel. It's then a trivial copy and run.

Comment: I will try Your idea . Best Regards @HenryGomersall.